# How to design React-Native Button

Tags: react-native

I am new to react-native and I want to design such a button, I tried and searched but could not find an answer

any help would be appreciated

[image]

Comment: Have you looked up the documentation? What did you try? https://reactnative.dev/docs/button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this aproach, with radiusBorder you can achieve something close to you're looking for:

```
 import React from 'react';
 import { View, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, Text } from 'react-native';

 export default function NAME() {
   return (
     <TouchableOpacity>
      <View style={styles.wrapperContainer}>
        <View style={styles.Container}>
          <Text>Foo</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
     </TouchableOpacity>
   );
 }

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    Container: {
      height: 50,
      width: 100,
      alignItems: 'center',
      background: '#1f90f0',
      borderRadius: 5,
      justifyContent: 'center',
      borderTopLeftRadius: 50,
      borderLeftWidth: 2,
      borderLeftColor: 'lightgray'
    },
  wrapperContainer: {
      background: 'lightgray',
      width: 100,
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `TouchableOpacity` instead. That way you can customize the button however you want it to be.

https://reactnative.dev/docs/touchableopacity

```
import React from 'react';
import {TouchableOpacity, View, Text} from 'react-native';

export default function NAME() {
  return(
    <View>
      <TouchableOpacity style={{padding: 10, borderWidth: 1, borderColor: '#000'}}>
        <Text>Text goes here</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Edit: This is the closest I got for what you are looking for.

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';

export default function NAME() {
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity>
      <View style={styles.Container}>
        <View style={styles.ButtonShape} />
      </View>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  Container: {
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
  },
  ButtonShape: {
    borderLeftWidth: 20,
    width: 120,
    borderLeftColor: 'transparent',
    borderRightColor: 'transparent',
    borderTopColor: 'blue',
    borderTopWidth: 50,
  },
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but I mean the left button that has a skewed shadow. How to design it.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom button in react-native by using TouchableOpacity and if you want to perform any function when the user press that button you can use **onPress** prop.

```
 import React from 'react';
 import {TouchableOpacity, View, Text} from 'react-native';

 const FunctionName = () => {

  return(

   <View>

   <TouchableOpacity style={styles.buttonStyling}>
    <Text>Button Name</Text>
  </TouchableOpacity>

  </View>
 );
}
```

export defaultFunctionName;